# What's the difference between shock waves and acoustic waves?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, acoustics, plasma-physics, shock-waves

What's the difference between [shock waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) and [acoustic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave)?
I tried and searched around this subject, but I could not find any relative article about it. Please help me find a proper answer.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave. The major difference is within the first paragraph of each article.

Comment: You may find the following useful/helpful:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139436/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136596/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/306184/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210097/59023.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between shock waves and acoustic waves?

In principle, an acoustic wave can be of the same mode as a [shock wave](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nonlinear_wave#Shock_waves) if the speed of communication in the medium in question is the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound).  As I stated in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139436/59023, a shock forms from a nonlinearly steepening wave.  In principle, all longitudinal, compressional modes will steepen which can be though of as an amplitude dependence in the [phase speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity).  That is, higher amplitude parts of the wave will propagate faster.

In the fluid equations of motion, steepening comes from the $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}$ term.  Further, the speed of sound is defined as $C_{s}^{2} = \partial P/\partial \rho$, where $P$ is the scalar pressure and $\rho$ is the mass density.  In a sound wave, the mode is longitudinal and so the peaks(troughs) are compression(rarefaction) regions.  In the absence of [energy dissipation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipation), a sound wave will steepen and eventually undergo [wave breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave).  If there is energy dissipation, but it does not become a *strong* parameter until the steepening causes the gradient scale length becomes comparable to the mean free path for particle-particle collisions, then it is possible for a steepening sound wave to reach a stable discontinuity, called a shock wave.

So the short answer is a shock wave is the nonlinear extrema of an acoustic wave in a collisional medium where the speed of sound is the relevant communication speed.

I should note that the speed of sound is not the relevant speed in all mediums, e.g., in plasmas it is the fast mode speed (i.e., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023).