Busemann biplane wave drag
The Busemann Biplane consists of two diamond shapes that cancel each-others shockwaves. Which means that it generates no sonic boom or wave drag.
It can be modified to generate lift with a slight sonic boom and CFD simulations (which include skin friction) estimate a lift-to-drag ratio of around 20 (PDF link) vs 7-8 for the Concorde. But for now let's focus on the original zero-lift design.
A shockwave is a sudden discontinuity. Much like a hydraulic jump, it is an irreversible process that generates entropy. So this can't be "undone" by the rarefaction fan at the back. Does this mean that the article is wrong and that the shockwaves, even if there is no sonic boom, still steal energy from the biplane (in addition to the skin friction)?

If i'm reading this correctly, it does not say that there is no shock.  It says there is no specific kind of shock (a N-type shock) which is associated with sonic booms and wave drag.

@CortAmmon they seem to indicate that the drag from the shockwaves is zero if you don't need lift: "The Busemann concept can eliminate form shock drag but not that due to lift. Busemann's original geometry eliminated all wave drag and hence also lift." Which does not make sense given shocks generate entropy.

If you are plowing through a compressible medium with an incompressible piston faster than the speed of sound, there will be a shock wave.  There is no way to cancel that and there will always be aerodynamic drag because you cannot suddenly ignore conservation of energy and momentum.  It is possible to reduce the sound intensity of a sonic boom (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/271088/59023) but it won't be zero.

@KevinKostlan I think there may be imprecision in the wording.  I'm not finding quotes that directly state "there is no drag from any type of shock wave," but lots and lots of quotes pointing to minimizing it by preventing the wave-drag associated with those shock waves propagating out to infinity.  A few sources distinguished between wave drag and pressure drag, so its feasible the shape is changing the nature of the shock so much that it is now book-kept differently.

There are also lots of statements about the complete elimination of specific classes of shock waves.  It would be easy for imprecise language to inadvertently turn that into "elimination of all shock waves," especially given that those particular classes of shock waves are so important when looking into drag.

@CortAmmon Yes that seems to be what is going on. So it is much less shockwave drag, but not quite zero. A supersonic 20:1 glide ratio would be very nice, if such a flying wing is ever built.
