# How does a sound wave behave at a phase transition?

Tags: frequency, phase-transition, shock-waves

I wonder about the following:

A shock wave is propagating from within a solid body outside into a liquid. How will it behave? Especially, will the frequency remain the same?

Comment: What are you asking - experiment or theory?

Comment: Tbh, I didn't expect a difference. Sure, on a very small measurement scale level there will be a difference - but it shouldn't?

Comment: If the speed of sound is smaller in the liquid (very likely) and the two media are completely immersed within each other (e.g., solid suspended in liquid of semi-infinite volume), then the Mach number is likely to increase across the boundary if losses/dissipation due to the boundary transition are negligible.

Comment: @Ben Are you interested in the reflection of a shock wave from a free surface at the boundary of a solid with the formation of a liquid or gas?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thank you!. But how does the frequency behave?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's actually something out of the real world: I have something like a loudspeaker which is placed in a water tank and it uses pure single frequencies. I would like to know if those shock waves keep their frequencies when they propagate - through the liquid and at the case?

Comment: @Ben - Frequency?  It's a discontinuity so technically it is composed of all frequencies, right?

Comment: @Ben  A loudspeaker placed in a water does not produce shock waves. These are just sound waves of finite amplitude.

Comment: @honeste_vivere What exactly are "all" frequencies? With a single pure tone there should be - in theory - only one frequency?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, sure. Sorry, I mixed it. I thought it would be a shock wave in English.

Comment: @Ben - Shock waves are NOT single pure tones.  For instance, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136596/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/306184/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139436/59023.