# Can the wavelengths (sound, light) be infinite?

Tags: cosmology, waves

Can the wavelengths (sound, light) be infinite or are they limited by something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meant by infinite wavelength?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222495/what-is-meant-by-infinite-wavelength)

Answer (score 3):

By the relation $c=\lambda\nu,$
for an infinite wavelength $\lambda$ you would have zero frequency $\nu$.

Consider a plane wave with the usual phase factor
$$\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}-\nu t\right)+\phi_0\right).$$
For $\lambda=\infty$ and $\nu=0$
this simply reduces to $\cos(\phi_0)$,
i.e. a constant independent of position and time.

For light this just means a homogenous static electric field $\vec{E}$
and a homogenous static magnetic field $\vec{B}$.
For sound this means a homogenous static pressure $p$
and a homogenous steady wind with velocity $\vec{v}$.

Physically and mathematically there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

By the Planck-Einstein relation, 
$$ E = hc/ \lambda$$
For an infinite wavelength, you would have zero energy, which is problematic.
Also, you would need to measure this "infinite wavelength". What kind of mathematical shape would this look like? A constant? I guess if you consider the constant state to be "infinite wavelength", then yes; but noone would call an homogeneous electromagnetic field "infinite wavelength".