# Wave dispersion relation as a differntial equation

Tags: waves, dispersion

I have seen the following dispersion relation as a differential equation:
$$
\frac{ \partial \mathbf{k} }{ \partial t } + \left( \mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{k} = 0 \tag{1}
$$
in the page number 135 of the textbook Holton, J. R., & Hakim, G. J. (2013). An introduction to dynamic meteorology (5th ed., Vol. 88). Amsterdam: Elsevier.
, and also here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/381974/393802

But it does not make sense to me, so I am not sure it is a (propagated) typo or there is something I do not understand.

Let's follow the cited book and assume that we have a 2-dimensional wave and that the phase of the wave, $\phi$, is real. The wave number, $\mathbf{k}$ and the angular frequency, $\omega$, can be expressed as differential operations on the angular phase, $\phi$. The angular phase $\phi$ for a two dimensional wave can be expressed as $\phi = kx+ly- \omega t$, where $k$ and $l$ are the wave numbers in the $x$ and $y$ directions, respectively, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. The wave vector is defined as $ \mathbf{k} = k \mathbf{i} + l \mathbf{j} $, So, we can get the wave vector from the angular phase by applying the spatial gradient:
$$
\mathbf{k} = \nabla \phi = {\partial \phi \over \partial x} \mathbf{i} + {\partial \phi \over \partial y} \mathbf{j} \tag{2}
$$
Or, in matrix notation and assuming that the gradient is a row vector:
$$
\mathbf{k} = \nabla \phi = \left(
{\partial \phi \over \partial x} ,
{\partial \phi \over \partial y}\right) \tag{3}
$$

On the other hand we can get the angular frequency by applying the time derivative on the angular phase:
$$
\omega = - {\partial \phi \over \partial t} \tag{4}
$$

Now we can take the time derivative of [3](/questions/tagged/3) to get:
$$
{\partial \mathbf{k} \over \partial t} = 
 {\partial \over \partial t} \nabla \phi =
 \nabla {\partial \phi \over \partial t} =
 - \nabla \omega
 \tag{5}
$$
where we have used [4](/questions/tagged/4) in the last step.
That is to say:
$$
{\partial \mathbf{k} \over \partial t} + \nabla \omega = 0
\tag{6}
$$

We now recall that $\omega$ is a function of $\mathbf{k}$ (dispersion relation), id est, $\omega (x, y) = \omega (\mathbf{k} (x,y)) = \omega(k(x,y),l(x,y))$, so that we can rewrite the gradient of $\omega$ in "wavenmber coordinates" as:
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla \omega &= \left(
{\partial \omega \over \partial x} ,
{\partial \omega \over \partial y}\right)
\\
&= \left({\partial \omega \over \partial k} {\partial k \over \partial x} + {\partial \omega \over \partial l} {\partial l \over \partial x}
,
{\partial \omega \over \partial k} {\partial k \over \partial y} + {\partial \omega \over \partial l} {\partial l \over \partial y}
\right)
\\
&= 
\left(
{\partial \omega \over \partial k} ,
{\partial \omega \over \partial l}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\partial k \over \partial x & \partial k \over \partial y\\
\partial l \over \partial x & \partial l \over \partial y
\end{array}\right)
\\
&= \nabla _k \omega \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k}
\end{align}
\tag{7}
$$
where $\nabla \mathbf{k}$ is the jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{k}$.

Replacing this into ec [6](/questions/tagged/6), gives:
$$
\frac{ \partial \mathbf{k} }{ \partial t } + \nabla _k \omega \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} = 0 \tag{8}
$$

Recalling that the group velocity is $\mathbf{V}_{g} = \nabla _k \omega$:
$$
\frac{ \partial \mathbf{k} }{ \partial t } + \mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} = 0 \tag{9}
$$

This contrasts with eq. [1](/questions/tagged/1), because $\mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} \ne \left( \mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{k}$

Or, at least, this is what I think. To see this, let $\mathbf{V}_{g} = (v_x, v_y)$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{k}  &=
\left[ 
   ( v_x, v_y) \cdot
   \left(
      {\partial \over \partial x} ,
      {\partial \over \partial y}
   \right)
\right]
\left(
 k, l
\right)
\\
&= \left(v_x {\partial \over \partial x} +
         v_y {\partial \over \partial y}
\right) (k, l)
\\
&= \left(v_x {\partial k \over \partial x} +
         v_y {\partial k \over \partial y},
         v_x {\partial l \over \partial x} +
         v_y {\partial l \over \partial y}
\right)
\end{align}
\tag{10}
$$

In order to compare this with $\mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k}$, recall that $\mathbf{V}_{g} = \nabla _k \omega = \left({\partial \omega \over \partial k}, {\partial \omega \over \partial l} \right) = ( v_x, v_y )$, so that the second line of eq. [9](/questions/tagged/9) is:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{V}_{g} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} &= \nabla \omega
\\
&= \left(
{\partial \omega \over \partial x} ,
{\partial \omega \over \partial y}\right)
\\
&= \left({\partial \omega \over \partial k} {\partial k \over \partial x} + {\partial \omega \over \partial l} {\partial l \over \partial x}
,
{\partial \omega \over \partial k} {\partial k \over \partial y} + {\partial \omega \over \partial l} {\partial l \over \partial y}
\right)
\\
&=
\left({v_x} {\partial k \over \partial x} + {v_y} {\partial l \over \partial x}
,
{v_x} {\partial k \over \partial y} + {v_y} {\partial l \over \partial y}
\right)
\end{align}
\tag{11}
$$

Which is not the same as eq. [10](/questions/tagged/10)
What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry! I had a mistake because, in some formulas, I used $\phi$ where I had to use $\omega$. I have edited and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my way of proceeding. Most of it agrees with you, but I can't quite pin down where we differ. Perhaps the mixed-partial trick of interchanging the $i$ and $j$?

The essential feature of  a wave train   is that at any particular
point of space and  time, ${\bf x}$ and $t$,  it has a definite  phase
$\Theta({\bf x},t)$. Once we know this phase, we can define the
local frequency $\omega$ and wave-vector ${\bf k}$ by
$$
\omega= -\left(\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial
t}\right)_{\bf x},\qquad  k_i = \left(\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial
x_i }\right)_t. 
$$
These definitions are motivated by the idea that
$$
\Theta({\bf x},t)\sim {\bf k}\cdot {\bf x} -\omega t,
$$
at least locally.

The subscripts on the partial derivatives indicate  what is being left fixed when we
differentiate. We must be  careful about this,  because we
want to use the dispersion equation to express  $\omega$ as
a function of ${\bf k}$ and  ${\bf x}$, and the wave-vector
${\bf k}$ will itself be a function of ${\bf x}$ and $t$.

We wish to understand  how ${\bf k}$ changes as the wave
propagates through a slowly varying  medium. We  introduce
the inhomogeneity by assuming that the dispersion equation
$\omega=\omega ({\bf k})$, which is initially derived for a
uniform medium, can  be extended to $\omega =\omega({\bf
k}, {\bf x})$, where the $\bf x$ dependence arises, for
example, as a result of a position-dependent  refractive
index. This assumption is only an approximation, but  it is
a good approximation when the  distance over which the
medium changes is much larger than the distance between
wavecrests.

Applying the equality of  mixed partials to the definitions
of ${\bf k}$ and $\omega$ gives us
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
x_i }\right)_t= -\left(\frac{\partial k_i}{\partial
t }\right)_{\bf x},\quad \left(\frac{\partial k_i}{\partial
x_j }\right)_{x_i}= \left(\frac{\partial k_j}{\partial
x_i }\right)_{x_j}.
$$
Again the subscripts indicate  what is being left fixed when we
differentiate.

Now use the chain rule
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
x_i }\right)_t= \left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
x_i }\right)_{\bf k} + \left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
k_j }\right)_{\bf x}\left(\frac{\partial k_j}{\partial
x_i }\right)_t.
$$
We now  use  one of the previous mixed-partial identities   to interchange the $i$, $j$ labels  in the fixed-$t$ partial derivative, and so get
$$
\left(\frac{\partial k_i}{\partial
t }\right)_{\bf x}+ \left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
k_j }\right)_{\bf x}\left(\frac{\partial k_i}{\partial
x_j }\right)_t = -\left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
x_i }\right)_{\bf k}.
$$
Interpreting the left hand side as a convective derivative
$$
\frac{dk_i}{dt}\equiv \left(\frac{\partial k_i}{\partial
t }\right)_{\bf x}+({\bf V}_g\cdot\nabla) k_i,
$$
we see that we percive a time rate of change of the wavevector as
$$
\frac {dk_i}{dt}= -\left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
x_i }\right)_{\bf k}
$$
provided we are moving at velocity
$$
\frac {dx_i}{dt}=({\bf V}_g)_i= \left(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
k_i }\right)_{\bf x}.
$$
Since this is the group velocity, the  packet of
waves is actually travelling at this speed.  The last two  equations
therefore  tell us how the orientation and wavelength of
the  wave train evolve if we ride along with the packet as
it is refracted by the inhomogeneity.

The formulae
$$
\dot {\bf k} = -\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
{\bf x} },
\\
\dot {\bf x}= \phantom -\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial
{\bf k} },
$$
are *Hamilton's ray equations*. Their similarity to the Hamilton equations of mechanics should be manifest.

Comment: Wow!, your approach is more general than mine, because I regard that all the dependence of $\omega$ on $\mathbf{x}$ (position vector) is through $\mathbf{k}$, and only through $\mathbf{k}$, and you admit that there can be a dependence that is not through $\mathbf{k}$. In the end, you get to a formula that, when the dependence is only through $\mathbf{k}$, reduces to eq. 1 of the OP, so that it would not be a typo. But I still have to find were my reasoning differs from yours.

Comment: Eureka!, as you pointed out: "the mixed-partial trick of interchanging the i and j" is the point. It is the property of ${\left( \partial k_i \over x_j \right) _{x _i}} = {\left( \partial k_j \over x_i \right) _{x _j} }$ that makes $\mathbf{V _g} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} = \left( \mathbf{V _g} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{k}$. So, both versions, eq. 1 of OP and eq.9 of OP, are equivalent and correct, but eq.1 is more attractive, because it says that the local tendency of $\mathbf{k}$ equals its advection.

Comment: Or more generally (thanks to your deduction), the local tendency of $\mathbf{k}$ equals its advection minus the gradient of $\omega$ holding $k$ constant.

Comment: @Antonio Serrana:  I learned this from James Lighthill's book "Waves in fluids" The identification $\omega({\bf x}, {\bf k})$ with the Hamiltonian $H({\bf x}, {\bf p})$ of classical mechanics is  basically the wave particle duality of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in coordinates.
Let $$\left[\nabla \mathbf k\right]_{ij}  = \frac{\partial k_j}{\partial x_i}$$

then
$$\left[\mathbf v \cdot \nabla \mathbf k\right]_j  = \sum_i v_i \frac{\partial k_j}{\partial x_i}$$
and $$\left[(\mathbf v \cdot \nabla) \mathbf k\right]_j  = \sum_i v_i \frac{\partial} {\partial x_i}k_j\\=\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial k_j}{\partial x_i}$$

Comment: Sorry, I do not manage well with this notation. I have edited a the question to provide a more detailed comparison of the two versions. Perhaps I have a mistake, but do not know where.

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in your second formula and that it should be $ \sum _j v _j {\partial k _j \over \partial x _i }$, id est, the subscript of $v$ and the summation index, should be $j$. Or alternatively, $ \sum _i v _i {\partial k _i \over \partial x _j }$ (in this way, $j$ denotes the component of the result, as is intended in your original formula).

Comment: I retract from my above comment because, as mike stone has pointed out, ${\partial k_i \over \partial x_j} = {\partial k_j \over \partial x_i}$, so your formula is correct.

Comment: an "engineer's way" of knowing how to place the indices correctly is to remember that $\nabla = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$ is a "row vector" while $\mathbf v = [v_i]$ is a column vector, and by $\mathbf v \cdot \nabla$ a "scalar" differential operator is meant that we can write as $\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$, so that  in $(\mathbf v \cdot \nabla) \mathbf k$ the operator $\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$ is applied to each component of $\mathbf k = [k_j]$ separately.

Comment: And, how would you express with this notation that $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k} = (\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla ) \mathbf{k}$ when ${\partial k_i \over \partial x_j} = {\partial k_j \over \partial x_i}$ ?

Comment: $\nabla \mathbf k$ is a *matrix* whose first row is $\frac{\partial k_1}{\partial x_j}$, second row is $\frac{\partial k_2}{\partial x_j}$, etc., $j=1,2,...n$. To form $\mathbf v \cdot \nabla \mathbf k$ you multiply this matrix with a column vector $[v_1, v_2, ...]^T$

Comment: So, I would say $[\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{k}]_j = \sum _i v_i {\partial k_i \over \partial x_j} = \sum _i v_i {\partial k_j \over \partial x_i} = (\sum _i v_i {\partial  \over \partial x_i}) k_j = [(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla ) \mathbf{k}]_j$. Do you agree?