# Hydrodynamics shock wave Riemann problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, shock-waves

I'm studying the Riemann problem in hydrodynamics. I've learned that a *rarefaction wave* and a *shock wave* will be created.

From what I know, a [shock wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) is a wave which travels at higher speeds than the speed of sound in that medium. However, I can't  find a way to fit my definition to the problem, as there is no need for the wave to travel at such speeds in the Riemann problem. Therefore, I would like to ask what is exactly a shock wave in this field of physics.

Comment: Relevant/Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/249848/59023, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/306184/59023, and/or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136596/59023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, the [Riemann problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_problem) does not say anything about [shock waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave).  It is just an [initial value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) of the form:
$$
q\left( x, t=0 \right) = \begin{cases}
  q_{L} & \text{for x $\leq$ 0} \\
  q_{R} & \text{for x $>$ 0} \tag{0}
\end{cases}
$$
where $x$ is a spatial variable and $t$ a temporal variable.  The problem states that at time zero, all values of $q$ are constant for negative $x$ and all values of $q$ are constant for positive $x$, but they transition between these two constant states in some region or a discontinuity, depending on the problem you wish to address.

The problem is ideally suited for 1D [gas dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressible_flow), e.g., there is a removable wall at $x$ = 0 and two gases on either side with different densities and temperatures.

In the case of full [hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics) to which you refer, the dummy variable $q$ represents the following multiple variables:  density, pressure, and bulk flow velocity (or speed for 1D problem).  The Riemann problem is often used as a useful tool for initial value problems involving shock waves, e.g., [shock tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_tube) problems are ideally suited for this.

> However, I can't find a way to fit my definition to the problem, as there is no need for the wave to travel at such speeds in the Riemann problem. Therefore, I would like to ask what is exactly a shock wave in this field of physics.

The resulting discontinuities may or may not be shock waves.  If the initial conditions have a large enough gradient between the two regions for the parameters, a shock wave would form.  The gradient is small, then a simple acoustic wave will form.  If proper dissipation (e.g., viscosity) is included, the initial discontinuity sound wave will *smooth out* (i.e., decrease in amplitude/strength) into a gradual change in the absence of external work.

The whole shock thing arises from large pressure/flow/density gradients that cause large enough forces to maintain a shock.  The initiation of the shock requires some irreversible energy transformation (in thermodnyamics, this is equivalent to entropy production).

Comment: Even in 1D, velocity is still velocity -- it isn't forced to be positive (ie. speed). Otherwise, spot on answer.

Comment: @tpg2114 - Fair point as it can still have a sign...